# Bracket with Arrow for deduce argument

Tags: arrows

[image]

hello. how do this, an arrow with rightarrow
for maths deduce and argument
i tried

```
\biggr\}\Rightarrow
```

but is not tottaly near
thanks

Comment: The assumption is that `We are the sun` is actually multiple lines, hence the use of a right-facing brace `\}`, correct? And is this in a big equation? Perhaps provide some more context, please...

Comment: You can use negative space i.e. `\!`.

Comment: thanks i don't know about negative space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}

\sffamily
We are the sun $\biggr\}\negmedspace{\boldsymbol\Rightarrow}$ and blue

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: excelent just what i need it